# Iterating Over Xml using findall , Lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, findall

I have the following xml :

```
<head>
  <body>
    <para>
      <Run>
        <Runprop>
           <highlight val="red"/>
        <break/>
        <text>
         Hello there
        </text>
        </RunProp>
      </Run>
      <Run>
        <break/>
      </Run>
      <Run>
         <text>
          See you there
         </text>
      </Run>
    </para> ..
  </body>
</head>
```

I want to extract all text with the `highlight` "red" value. Note that `highlight` tag is one level down to that of the text tag. And the conditions are:

1. For every paragraph , add an extra space .
2. If the break tag is encountered whilst iterating over parents of `highlight` tag , add a space.
3. Extract text only corresponding to the `highlight` tag

What I have done is:

```
text=""                                #initialize an empty string
for p in lxml_tree.findall('para'): #itertate over each paragraph (all paragarpahs have the same tag name para)
    for r in p.findall("Run"):     #iterate over each run
         for a in r.iter(tag="highlight"): #search for highlight tag
            for b in a.iterancestors(): #go back to the parents
                if b.tag=="break":     #if break found
                   text+=" "           # add a space
                elif b.tag=="text":    # if text found
                   text+=''.join(b.text) #add text
```

The above doesn't seem to work as iterancestors travels all the way to the root node. How could i possibly iterate over the parents i.e. `Runprop`, `break`, and `text`?? I have implemented something similar to this for all the text and that worked..

**Edit 1**:
Just a flawed logic above , I would rather iterate over each `Run` in a paragraph , search for `break` first , then see if there's highlight within the `Runprop` and then extract text in the parent's sibling.

Comment: Is that typo or your `highlight` doesn't have a closing tag?

Comment: ohh wait , sorry it is a self closing tag.. will fix it.

Comment: `runprop` and `RunProp` too... not case matching :)

Comment: the description was just for clarity , I'll fix it anyways :)

Comment: one thing, I don't quite get what an extra space requirement means, can you explain a little more?

Comment: In Ms word sometimes when two words are entered without any space , they appear in different lines but when I extract text , these 2 words get merged. So I am giving an extra space at every break tag encountered..

Comment: so, insert space if `break` tag found, and regardless of spaces, just print `highlight` value and text inside?

Comment: yes but add a space for every paragraph as well as sometimes without an xml space preserve , they merge too. So that is no problem. If you are actually answering it and are confused , I can show you the code for all the text..

Comment: I have posted an answer, although not 100% whether I totally understand what you need exactly. Please take a look

Comment: yes I am , I'll port ur logic to suit my needs . Relative positions are the same , for eg runprop comes before break and text , but the  actual position will not be the same . so .next won't work. I'd opt for .itersiblings to iterate over nodes of the same level..

Comment: right, alternatively you may use `xpath` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix it after some thoughts and getting an idea from anzel's answer.

```
text=""          
for p in lxml_tree.findall('para'):   #iterate over paragraphs
    text+= " "                        #add spaces
    for r in p.findall("Run"):        #iterate over each run in para
         for a in r.findall("break"):  #search for break tag in it and add space if found
            text+= " "
         for b in r.findall('.//highlight[@val="red"]/../..//text'): #search for red highlight in that run and return text
             text+=''.join(b.text) # append text to main string
```

Comment: yes `xpath` is the way to go, feel happy to accept your own answer

Comment: actually its findall , xpath is more complex . thanks for your time . Hope you learnt something today as well..

Comment: FYI, yes findall uses `xpath` syntax, too :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your xml has a positional pattern where `<highlight>`, `<break />` and `<text>`, you actually don't need to go back to parent.

I'm going to use `iter` and `getnext` to achieve what you need:

```
from lxml import etree

html = '''
<head>
  <body>
    <para>
      <Run>
        <RunProp>
           <highlight val="red" />
        <break/>
        <text>
         Hello there
        </text>
        </RunProp>
      </Run>
      <Run>
        <break/>
      </Run>
      <Run>
         <text>
          See you there
         </text>
      </Run>
    </para> ..
  </body>
</head>'''

tree = etree.fromstring(html)

for node in tree.iter():
    if node.tag == 'para':
        node.text = '..your space here..' + node.text
        print node.text
    if node.tag == 'highlight':
        print node.values()
        if node.getnext().tag == 'break':
            print node.getnext().tag
            if node.getnext().getnext().tag == 'text':
                node.getnext().getnext().text = \
                    '..your space here..' + node.getnext().getnext().text
                print node.getnext().getnext().text
        elif node.getnext().tag == 'text':
            print node.getnext().text

..your space here....your space here..

['red']
break
..your space here....your space here..
         Hello there
```

to write the changes to a file:

```
etree.ElementTree(tree).write('output.xml', pretty_print=True)

cat output.xml
<head>
  <body>
    <para>..your space here..
      <Run>
        <RunProp>
           <highlight val="red"/>
        <break/>
        <text>..your space here..
         Hello there
        </text>
        </RunProp>
      </Run>
      <Run>
        <break/>
      </Run>
      <Run>
         <text>
          See you there
         </text>
      </Run>
    </para> ..
  </body>
</head>
```

Comment: check it out, +1 for you coz u gave me an idea.. :)